# Select dates with Selenium & Python

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver

i try to select the fromDate and toDate on the calendar of this page: https://jetsmart.com/cl/es/

What´s the problem, if i select the fromDate value:

```
driver.find_element_by_xpath("//div[@class='dayContainer']//span[@aria-label='Abril 1, 2021']").click()
```

The page select the April 1, but if i try to select the toDate value:

```
driver.find_element_by_xpath("//div[@class='dayContainer']//span[@aria-label='Abril 30, 2021']").click()
```

This doesn´t work and returns the following error:

```
Message: element not interactable
```

This is the code:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from webdriver_manager.chrome import ChromeDriverManager
import time




driver = webdriver.Chrome(ChromeDriverManager().install())
driver.implicitly_wait(15)

driver.get('https://jetsmart.com/cl/es/')

time.sleep(10)
try:
    elem_from = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//button[@id='onesignal-slidedown-cancel-button']").click()
except:
    pass
    
time.sleep(5)
elem_from = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//input[@ref='from']").click()
time.sleep(5)
elem_from1 = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//ul[@ref='citySelector']//li[@data-citycode='SCL']").click()
time.sleep(5)
elem_from1 = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//ul[@ref='citySelector']//li[@data-citycode='ARI']").click()
time.sleep(5)

elem_from2 = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//span[@class='flatpickr-next-month']").click()

from_time = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//div[@class='dayContainer']//span[@aria-label='Abril 1, 2021']")
from_time.click()
time.sleep(5)
to_time = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//div[@class='dayContainer']//span[@aria-label='Abril 30, 2021']")
to_time.click()
```

Answer (score 0):

Your issue was getting the right span after it opens there are 4 similar divs with 4 spans that can be the same. You could also get the third and just index it by one.

```
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 20)
driver.get('https://jetsmart.com/cl/es/')
try:
    wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR,"#onesignal-slidedown-cancel-button"))).click()
except:
    pass

elem_from = wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH,"//input[@ref='from']")))
elem_from.click()

elem_from1 = wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH,"//ul[@ref='citySelector']//li[@data-citycode='SCL']")))
elem_from1.click()

elem_from1 = wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH,"//ul[@ref='citySelector']//li[@data-citycode='ARI']")))
elem_from1.click()

elem_from2 = wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH,"//span[@class='flatpickr-next-month']")))
elem_from2.click()

from_time = wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH,"(//span[@aria-label='Abril 1, 2021'])[1]")))
from_time.click()

to_time = wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH,"(//span[@aria-label='Abril 30, 2021'])[3]")))
to_time.click()
```

You have 4 divs 1-2 match the months for the from and 3-4 for the other.

```
(//div[@class='dayContainer'])[1]//span[]
(//div[@class='dayContainer'])[3]//span[]
```

Imports

```
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait 
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
```